# how do I require 'rake' to be able to use FileList in .gemspec?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler

I am using `:path => '/path/to/gem'` functionality of bundler to build and use a modified upstream gem, which uses `Rake::FileList` in its .gemspec.

At this stage, the bundle I'm installing is not yet activated, or maybe the order things are installed forbids bundler from using `rake`.

I am using ruby 1.8.7.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem "rake"
gem "foreign_gem", :path => '/home/user/src/foreign_gem'
```

The error I get:

```
$ bundle install
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler 
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks! 
/home/ilya/src/foreign_gem/foreign_gem.gemspec:11: uninitialized constant FileList (NameError)
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:426:in 'initialize'
        from /home/user/src/foreign_gem/foreign_gem.gemspec:1:in 'new'
        from /home/user/src/foreign_gem/foreign_gem.gemspec:1
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add `require 'rake'` at the top of your `foreign_gem.gemspec` file in order to use `FileList`.

I don't know if this is a best practice, but it should work.